# Conservar dato al pasar un puntero por referencia - C++

Tags: c++, punteros, paso-por-referencia

Estoy aprendiendo a pasar punteros por referencia a funciones.
Al cargar este código:

```
using namespace std;

void paso(int*&referencia)
{
    int* dir_cambio,m=2;
    dir_cambio=&m;
    referencia=dir_cambio;
    cout << "Dirección función: " << referencia << endl;
    cout << "Dato función: " << *referencia << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *dir_entero,n=13;
    dir_entero=&n;
    cout << "Dirección inicial: " << dir_entero << endl;
    cout << "Dato inicial: " << *dir_entero << endl;
    paso(dir_entero);
    cout << "Dirección final: " << dir_entero << endl;
    cout << "Dato final: " << *dir_entero << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Me imprime:

````
Dirección inicial: 0x7ffd7f3b031c
Dato inicial: 13
Dirección función: 0x7ffd7f3b02ec
Dato función: 2
Dirección final: 0x7ffd7f3b02ec
Dato final: 32743```
````

Mi pregunta es: ¿Por qué no me aparece 2 como dato final?

La otra pregunta sería: ¿Cómo hago para poder usar el valor 2 en la función main usando el puntero dir_entero?

Edit:

El problema es el ámbito en el cual se trabaja. Quedó claro.
Sin embargo, hay algo que me desconcierta... Si coloco:

````
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void paso(int**referencia)
{```
    int *dir_cambio, m = 2;
    dir_cambio = &m;
    *referencia = dir_cambio;
}

int main()
{
    int *dir_entero,n=13;
    dir_entero=&n;
    cout  << *dir_entero << endl;
    paso(&dir_entero);
    cout << *dir_entero << endl;   
    return 0;
}
````

Me devuelve el 2, como espero.
Pero, con solo cambiar la antepenúltima línea a como se muestra ahora:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void paso(int**referencia)
{
    int *dir_cambio, m = 2;
    dir_cambio = &m;
    *referencia = dir_cambio;
}

int main()
{
    int *dir_entero,n=13;
    dir_entero=&n;
    cout  << *dir_entero << endl;
    paso(&dir_entero);
    cout << "El dato final es: " <<  *dir_entero << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Ya vuelve a tener un comportamiento aleatorio como antes.
¿A qué se debe esto?

Comment: Lo que estás haciendo es cambiar la dirección, lo sé ya que unos meses tuve el mismo error. Lo que puedes hacer es intercambiar los datos dentro, uno lo pasas directo y para que el otro no se pierda puedes utilizar una variable local solo para guardarlo. Recuerda eliminarla al final

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿ Por qué no me aparece 2 como dato final ?

Porque en tu función `paso( )`, estás asignando a `referencia` la dirección de tu variable **automática** `m`.

Las variables automáticas son aquellas [cuyo tiempo de vida se limita al ámbito en el que se declaran](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). El compilador utiliza una determinada zona de memoria **de forma temporal** para crearlas, y dicha memoria es reutilizada para otras cosas cuando tu variable se destruye.

En tu caso, el ámbito es **tu función `paso( )`**. Es decir, `m` **deja de existir** al salir de tu función (el compilador reutiliza ese espacio para otras cosas), por lo que tu puntero *modificado* `dir_entero` queda apuntando a una dirección incorrecta. Mejor dicho, a una dirección que **ya no contiene lo que tú esperas**.

> ¿Cómo hago para poder usar el valor 2 en la función main usando el puntero dir_entero?

Lo tienes complicado. Tal y como lo has planteado, ya has visto el problema. No puedes usar una variable automática declarada en una función una vez que sales de ella.

Una posible solución es modificar un poco tu código, de forma que tu función `paso( )` reciba 2 argumentos ... algo parecido a lo que hace `std::swap( )`:

```
void paso(int*&referencia, int&nuevo_valor )
{
    int* dir_cambio;
    dir_cambio=&nuevo_valor;
    referencia=dir_cambio;
    cout << "Dirección función: " << referencia << endl;
    cout << "Dato función: " << *referencia << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int *dir_entero,n=13, m=2;
    dir_entero=&n;
    cout << "Dirección inicial: " << dir_entero << endl;
    cout << "Dato inicial: " << *dir_entero << endl;
    paso(dir_entero, m);
    cout << "Dirección final: " << dir_entero << endl;
    cout << "Dato final: " << *dir_entero << endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Era por el ámbito. Sin embargo, hay algo que me parece muy raro... Si pongo `#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void paso(int**referencia)
{
    int *dir_cambio, m = 2;
    dir_cambio = &m;
    *referencia = dir_cambio;
}

int main()
{
    int *dir_entero,n=13;
    dir_entero=&n;
    cout  << *dir_entero << endl;
    paso(&dir_entero);
    cout << *dir_entero << endl;   
    return 0;
}` Me devuelve 2! Pero si agrego un `cout << "El dato final es: "` antes de mostrar *dir_entero, ya se comporta como antes (edito mi preg para mostrar esto mejor)

Comment: Usar una variable fuera de su ámbito es un *comportamiento indefinido*. Puede funcionar. Puede fallar. El programa puede explotar. Puede funcionar sólo las noches de luna llena. Es una de las cosas *mas chulas* de C++ :-)

Comment: Jajajaja. Muchas gracias. Resuelto.